# Counting how many webpages were loaded in 1 day in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, statistics

How can I count how many webpages were loaded on a single day of Google Chrome use? I know it's saved because it lists all of them in history, but it'd take forever to count by hand!

I wanted to see this for bandwidth purposes. My ISP imposes a low limit (30GB per month, and we're a five person family). I wanted to see this and compare with what they think is "average" and what I view. I think they're way too low.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is probably overkill but you did say you were curious.

Chrome running in Windows 7 stores its history in an SQLite database file:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History
```

which you can open with an SQLite manager such as [SQLite Expert](http://www.sqliteexpert.com/) or [SQLiteStudio](http://sqlitestudio.one.pl/). **Make sure Chrome is closed first.**

You can query the database as follows:

```
select
  date(visit_time/1000000-11644473600, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as [Date],
  count(url) as [Pages]
from visits
group by [Date]
order by [Date] desc;
```

and get results such as:

```
Date         Pages
-----------  ----------
2011-11-15   23
2011-11-14   17
2011-11-13   46
2011-11-12   54
2011-11-11   29
...
```

Note: Date arithmetic calculations taken from [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141537/convert-datetime-fields-in-chrome-history-file-sqlite-to-readable-format/4112026#4112026).

Comment: Now that's really nifty! I'm a programmer too so this isn't too advanced for me.

Answer (score 3):

**Super easy method:** I guess you could copy and paste your history into a word document, and look at what line your cursor is on.

---

**1337 method:**

- Install the [History 2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cahejgbbfgmlmjgdjlibphdjeldhagkp#) extension.
- Copy the data into your favourite "programmer's" editor. (Notepad++, for me.)
- Use the following regexes:

  ```
  [^\s]*\s\[
  \]
  ```

  Replace all matches with absolutely nothing.
- Copy the data into a spreadsheet program (Microsoft Excel). Sum the data.

Comment: This works if it fits on one history page, if there's another page you'd need to copy it too. It will still work, I'm just noting it.

Comment: Ah, just tried it, it seems that when you paste it, it puts the time of access on a different line, so that won't work. BUT you could just divide the count by 2, and it'll work like that.

Comment: @Bubby4j Maybe use an extension? [History 2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cahejgbbfgmlmjgdjlibphdjeldhagkp#), copy the data, paste it into Notepad++, use a regex, copy the remaining numbers into Excel, and add them up.

Comment: There are [other extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/obciceimmggglbmelaidpjlmodcebijb), too. You could try installing them, and seeing which displays a full page of the day's history.